Delete all similar rows except first one
I have a database that contains several rows with the same values but a different timestamp. This was caused by an error and now I want to delete the incorrect values. There are too many values to delete manually. In one column, a number is counted up that is reset daily, so there may also be similar rows with different days, which is why I only want to delete similar rows that were written to the database one hour after the first entry. The entries must all contain the same value in the Mode and Value column.
This is what my datatable looks like:



id
timestamp
mode
value




1
2024-08-20 08:45:30
finished/X/2
55


2
2024-08-20 08:46:20
finished/X/2
55


3
2024-08-20 08:47:50
finished/X/2
55


4
2024-08-20 14:45:30
finished/Z/5
67


5
2024-08-20 14:47:15
finished/Z/5
67


6
2024-08-20 14:50:25
finished/Z/5
67


7
2024-08-21 10:20:45
finished/X/2
32


8
2024-08-21 10:21:30
finished/X/2
32


9
2024-08-21 12:20:55
finished/X/2
55



In this case, I would like to use the query to delete the rows in which the ID is 2, 3, 5, 6 & 8
I have already tried to filter the data with a join but got no result.

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Which dbms are you using? (The best answer might be product specific.) Also, date/time functions are too often product specific.

Though I can easily close this as a dupe for SQL Server, and I don't doubt MySQL has a similar duplicate.

Note that a [mcve] is supposed to include the expected result too. I.e. show us the table contents after the delete.

Please specify the logic which rows should be deleted and which not. I guess you want to keep only the earlies row per hour. But I shouldn't guess, you should be clear. You also write "In this case", but what are the other cases?

why should row 9 show up in the final result ?

The logic I described in my previous comment would be this: https://dbfiddle.uk/nhLL-Jxw. You will need to replace the DATEPART function by another one if you use another RDBMS. But as said, you're not clear if this logic is what you want.

i would probably create a new table with the good lines only and then replace the tables.

Guessing gaps and islands, @trillion .

@user24151662 Please check if the logic shown in the fiddle I provided is what you need. And tag your RDBMS.

In the given sample data, there's no 'a number is counted up that is reset daily' column. (ID isn't reset.) Are you (we) expected to create that column?

@user24151662 did you try the solution i added below?

Here is an updated SQL-Server based solution:
SELECT id,timestamp,mode,value FROM (
 SELECT *,row_number() OVER (partition by value,mode,cast(timestamp as date) order by timestamp) rn 
 FROM #tmp
 ) tbl WHERE rn=1 ORDER BY id

(See demo here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1858218/filter-out-the-first-values-of-repeated-entries )
Admittedly, this solution will not directly "delete" the duplicate rows from your table but instead it will create a new table containing the desired rows. You could insert the resulting rows into a new table, rename the tables accordingly and eventually delete the old one. This would give you time and opportunity to check the newly created table before releasing it to the public.

row 9 should be in the final result

I fixed my answer, so now only the first entries for values of the same mode and the same day in timestamp will be kept.

Thank you! This is what i was looking for and it worked how it should


Step 1: Use the LAG() function to bring the previous timestamp on the next row for the same value and mode

Step 2: Calculate the difference between the timestamp field and the previous timestamp from Step 2 and filter for the results.

Step 3: Delete the rows from table using delete from


LAG() uses partition by  clause to capture the grouped values i.e mode and value and then used order by clause to set the order i.e in your case is the timestamp field
NOTE: Since I am not sure which SQL are you using the timestampdiff function will need to be changed as per your SQL dialect. For MYSQL this function should work

with main as (
    select 
        id,
        timestamp,
        mode,
        value,
        lag(timestamp) over (partition by mode, value order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
    from 
        table
)
delete from table
where id in (
    select id
    from main
    where 
        prev_timestamp is not null
        and timestampdiff(hour, prev_timestamp, timestamp) <= 1
)


It seems that's incorrect because it would not fetch the row with ID 9

@trillion they need to delete similar record except the first not only select the data.

@JonasMetzler i edited the solution

Note that OP wants a DELETE.

Also tell OP (and the rest of us) which dbms this is for. (timestampdiff is a product specific function.)

@jarlh should be fine now, yes the timestampdiff I don't know which SQL is the person using

@jarlh for mysql this should work

1- Create a memory table.
2- Select Id, and rowId of all items ordered by timestamp and partitioned by mode and value. This will result in having a restart of counting of row Id based on mode changes.
3- Delete all where id in memory table with rowId > 1


CREATE TABLE test ENGINE=MEMORY
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by mode,value,date(timestamp)) AS RowID,id
           FROM YOUR_TABLE order by timestamp;
                      
          delete from YOUR_TABLE e where e.Id in (select t.Id
          from test t where rowId > 1);




What employees do you talk about?

I'm just giving a sample of how this can be implemented. Maybe I can better modify this to match exactly tables names in the post @Jonas Metzler

row 9 should be in the output
